# What are the consequences of calling both execute and executeOnExecutor?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask

Are there any known performance consequences to having some `AsyncTasks` in an app called using the `execute()` method and some called using the `executeOnExecutor()` method?

Will there be any threading issues?

There are occasions where I want the serial nature of `execute()` but there are other times where I need the parallel processing provided by `executeOnExecutor()`. However, I haven't been religious in the distinction between when one of these is called.

If there are performance penalties then I will attempt to make use of the more appropriate call at the right time.

Comment: Cf [the javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html): "*When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. **If you truly want parallel execution**, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.*"

Comment: In particular, I understand that you might encounter more threading issues if you don't synchronize your code properly when using executeOnExecutor.

Comment: I understood the difference between serial and parallel execution. The question was more to do with whether using both types in an application would interfere with one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the changes to use `executeOnExecutor()` in all viable places, there has been no discernible difference in performance, good or bad.